# How to add a measure dictionary to a PDDocument

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to create a GeoPDF from a georeferenced PNG image via PDFBox.
The PDF creation as such works without problem as there are numerous examples
for that task on the web. However, I need some help for the final step to
write a measure dictionary to the document in order to make it a GeoPDF.

From an existing GeoPDF document I can extract the "Measure" dictionary
like this: (I hope you don't mind that this is Kotlin.)

```
val measure: COSObject = document.getDocument().getObjectsByType(COSName.getPDFName("Measure")).first()
val dictionary: COSDictionary = measure.getObject() as COSDictionary
```

Now I have already created a new measure dictionary for the file I want
to write but I failed to get that into the document or in other words
what is the reverse operation of the above code fragment.

Comment: Does your PDF already have a viewport dictionary in the pages? There's probably more to do. See e.g. `PDPage.getViewports()`. Try this on the "good" PDF and see what's in it. Also use PDFDebugger to look at the structures in your PDF. Maybe share the file.

Comment: You are right. The document does not contain a viewport yet but that makes things a little bit clearer to me.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I just had to add the geoinformation which I already had to a viewport and add it to the document. I can now throw the generated PDF into QGIS and it is displayed at the correct location on the map. Thanks to @Tilman for the tips. For those who are interested I have added the relevant Kotlin code below. The concepts are explained in PDF_ISO_32000-2 in chapter 12.10 Geospatial features.

```
private fun writeGeoPdf(image: BufferedImage, westBound: Double, eastBound: Double, southBound: Double, northBound: Double,
                        imgFormat: String, outputStream: OutputStream) {
    require(imgFormat == "png" || imgFormat == "jpg") {"Unsupported PDF image format: $imgFormat. Must be either 'png' or 'jpg'."}

    PDDocument().use { document ->
        val pageWidth = image.width.toFloat()
        val pageHeight = image.height.toFloat()

        val page = PDPage(PDRectangle(pageWidth, pageHeight)).apply {
            viewports = listOf(createGeoViewport(image.width, image.height, westBound, eastBound, southBound, northBound))
        }

        PDPageContentStream(document, page).use { contentStream ->
            val pdImage = if (imgFormat == "png") LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, image) else JPEGFactory.createFromImage(document, image, compQuality["jpg"]!!)
            contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0f, 0f, pageWidth, pageHeight)
        }

        document.apply {
            addPage(page)
            save(outputStream)
        }
    }

}

private fun createGeoViewport(imgWidth: Int, imgHeight: Int, lonMin: Double, lonMax: Double, latMin: Double, latMax: Double): PDViewportDictionary {
    return PDViewportDictionary().apply {
        name = "Layer"
        bBox = PDRectangle(0.0f, 0.0f, imgWidth.toFloat(), imgHeight.toFloat())
        measure = PDMeasureDictionary(createGeoMeasureDictionary(lonMin, lonMax, latMin, latMax))
    }
}

private fun createGeoMeasureDictionary(lonMin: Double, lonMax: Double, latMin: Double, latMax: Double): COSDictionary {
    return COSDictionary().apply {
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Type")   , COSName.getPDFName("Measure"))
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Subtype"), COSName.getPDFName("GEO"))
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("GCS")    , createWGS84GCSDictionary())
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Bounds") , COSArray(listOf(COSInteger.get(0), COSInteger.get(1), COSInteger.get(0), COSInteger.get(0), COSInteger.get(1), COSInteger.get(0), COSInteger.get(1), COSInteger.get(1))))
        // The Double.toString() conversion is necessary to preserve the accuracy.
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("GPTS")   , COSArray(listOf(COSFloat(latMax.toString()), COSFloat(lonMin.toString()), COSFloat(latMin.toString()), COSFloat(lonMin.toString()), COSFloat(latMin.toString()), COSFloat(lonMax.toString()), COSFloat(latMax.toString()), COSFloat(lonMax.toString()))))
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("LPTS")   , COSArray(listOf(COSInteger.get(0), COSInteger.get(1), COSInteger.get(0), COSInteger.get(0), COSInteger.get(1), COSInteger.get(0), COSInteger.get(1), COSInteger.get(1))))
    }
}

private fun createWGS84GCSDictionary(): COSDictionary {
    return COSDictionary().apply {
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Type"), COSName.getPDFName("GEOGCS"))
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("EPSG"), COSInteger.get(4326))
        setItem(COSName.getPDFName("WKT") , COSString("GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"D_WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]]"))
    }
}

private val compQuality = mapOf (
    "png" to 1.0f,
    "jpg" to 0.75f,
    "webp" to 0.75f
)
```